# Select for every column the first value that is NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Table to select from:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
|______|______|______|______|
| NULL | foo  | NULL | NULL |
| bar  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | baz  |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Expected result:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
|______|______|______|______|
| bar  | foo  | NULL | baz  |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Is there a way to do this using a wildcard, so without having to list all column names in the query?

---

**Update:**

There's no such thing as `MAX(*) LIMIT 1`, but maybe by combining `COALESCE` with a `SELECT Field FROM (DESCRIBE <TableName>)` that ships all the column names?

I already tried many things with no success, but there must be a generic solution without listing all the column names. It's no problem if it's hacky.

Comment: No, it is not possible and also there is no first or last value without a column that defines the order of the rows.

Comment: I was thinking of something like `MAX(*) LIMIT 1` but it seems there's no such thing.

Comment: No. there isn't and even if there was MAX() does not return the *first* value in any way that way you define it.

Comment: You could use `COALESCE`, but you'd still need to list the columns.

Comment: http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/mysql-eval implements a pure MySQL eval() function for MySQL, so you could theoretically construct your query as a string and then use that to run it, but yuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested on MySQL 8.0.29:

```
select
  first_value(col1) over (order by case when col1 is null then 1 else 0 end, id) as col1,
  first_value(col2) over (order by case when col2 is null then 1 else 0 end, id) as col2,
  first_value(col3) over (order by case when col3 is null then 1 else 0 end, id) as col3,
  first_value(col4) over (order by case when col4 is null then 1 else 0 end, id) as col4
from mytable
limit 1;
```

Result:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
+------+------+------+------+
| bar  | foo  | NULL | baz  |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: I will accept this if nobody posts a generic solution. Not so bad, the lines between `select` and `from` I can easily generate for all columns when constructing the statement. Btw, I think the `, id` parts you should remove.

Comment: Are there more than one non-NULL value in each column? How do you tell which value is "first"?

Comment: Each column may contain any number of null and non-null values. The "first" can be any one of the non-nulls. The one that is found first.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Please test this:

VERSION-1

```
SELECT T1.Col1,T2.Col2,COALESCE(T1.Col3) AS Col3, T4.Col4
FROM TblNoNull T1
JOIN (SELECT(Col2) FROM TblNoNull) T2 ON T1.Col1 <>T2.Col2
JOIN (SELECT(Col4) FROM TblNoNull) T4 ON T2.Col2 <>T4.Col4;
```

If we test it, It returns:

[image: GGG]

VERSION-2

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.Col1,T2.Col2,T3.Col3, T4.Col4
FROM TblNoNull T1
JOIN (SELECT(Col2) FROM TblNoNull) T2 ON T1.Col1 <>T2.Col2
JOIN (SELECT(Col3) FROM TblNoNull) T3 ON T3.Col3 IS NULL
JOIN (SELECT(Col4) FROM TblNoNull) T4 ON T2.Col2 <>T4.Col4;
```

Let's test it:

[image: AZAZAZAZAD]

Comment: Thanks very much for your effort, I find however Bill's solution neater.

Comment: You're welcome. I am pleased that your problem is solved. That's the important thing here. Somebody solves it using joins, others using window function. Pick the one who suits you the best. Stay safe.